# Auto archive is not running on Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, autoarchive

I'm trying to archive emails in Outlook 2007. I set up Auto archive to archive anything older then X amount of months but it didn't archive anything. After a little Googling I discovered that the date that counts is the Modified date, not the Sent or Received dates. I reset the amount of months taking into account the modified date of the emails but it still isn't being archived.

What other setting/issues do I need to check for?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, and the solution in my case was that the default Autoarchive setting MUST be turned on:

Outlook > Tools > Options > Other > Autoarchive

[x] Run Autoarchive every [n] days

[x] Archive or delete old items

Set a high value (e.g. 99 Months), and a well-known destination PST to reduce the chance that Outlook may move items unexpectedly.  Then Outlook will process/respect your individual folders' Autoarchive settings.

This is a change from Outlook 2003, where the global option was not necessary and Outlook would still autoarchive based on individual folders' settings.

Comment: +1. This worked for me. Note that I had to manually enter 99 months, the spinner control would only let me go up to 60.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [article](http://www.howto-outlook.com/faq/archivenotworking.htm) about this issue and it suggests checking the following:

- Excluded from AutoArchive
- Modified date
- Damaged archive.pst
- Full archive.pst
- Full mailbox

Comment: Thanks for the link, but none of the given causes correspond to the situation. A damaged .pst file is the only one I can't rule out conclusively, but since I created them today I tend to doubt that its corrupt.

Comment: @ssvarc: you can rule out a damaged PST by running SCANPST on it.

Comment: @ssarcv: are you running the archive operation manually (File > Archive) or have you configured it to run at specific intervals (Tools > Options > Other > Autoarchive)?  When setting up autoarchiving, did you click the **Apply these settings to all folders now** button?